# In the context of tertiary education in nursing, what does "traditional" mean?

Tags: meaning, terminology

Someone described themselves as doing a traditional nursing university degree. In this context, what does "traditional" mean?

1. Nursing using [traditional medicine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_medicine)?
2. Nursing involving traditional medicine as the mainstream practice not involving alternative medicine, also known as "medicine"? (From a disambiguation message on the previously linked page)
3. Something else?

Comment: You did not specify if you meant traditional-nursing degree vs traditional nursing-degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, I think it means a full length degree, not an accelerated one.

For example, http://www.umsl.edu/~nursingweb/Pre-Licensure%20BSN%20Programs/traditional.html has under "Pre-Licensure BSN Programs" both "Accelerated" and "Traditional".

Comment: FTR, I'm fairly sure that is correct, AG.  (It has absolutely no connection to "traditional V. holistic medicine".)